# Why has my battery gauge on my '94 Ford Thunderbird stopped working?

Tags: electrical, ford, battery, gauges

Today the battery gauge stopped working and the needle rests just before the 0. The car itself cranks, starts, and sounds like it always has. However, there used to be this intermittent buzzing noise from time to time and my battery gauge needle did "jump" whenever I used my turn signals. Obviously these two things have stopped now.

Comment: Fuses checked ?

Comment: No, but I should do that. I've that the '94 has wiring/electrical issues. Thanks!